# Friendly return message when POST or GET fails or succeeds

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How do I get a friendly message returned to my client when a GET or POST succeeds of fails?

**serializers.py**

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Class to serialize Brand objects
    """
    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = 'id'

class BrandSignupSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """
    Create Brand profile
    """
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    brand = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, write_only=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    website = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = ('name', 'brand', 'email', 'phone', 'website')
        unique = 'email'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        brand = Brand.objects.create(**validated_data)
        brand.save()
        return brand

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

**views.py**

```
class BrandList(generics.ListAPIView):
    """
    List all Brands
    HTTP: GET
    """
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer


class BrandDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    List one Brand
    HTTP: GET
    """
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSerializer

class BrandSignup(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Brand signup
    HTTP POST
    """
    queryset = Brand.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BrandSignupSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: Can you add example what responses you need to obtain?

Comment: The reason that a POST/GET failed and a simple "success" message if it went well

Comment: Reason of failure should be added to response by default. Isn't you have error message in response when status code is 400?

Comment: It's a very generic one. There is no information about why the failure occurred. But maybe I need to do a bit more digging. I expected it to be something that I needed to code in ie on the `create` function

Comment: create a dict of key "return error codes" and its respective message you want to display to client as values  make each call inside try catch block and in catch return the respective error message based on the response code  to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can pass a dict in your `Response` where you can insert custom information, for example the serializer data, a custom message, the status and a status code as a string:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    if (serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)) :
        response_details = {
            'data': serializer.data,
            'message': "Your custom success message",
            'code': "201",
            'status': HTTP_201_CREATED
        }
    else :
        response_details = {
            'data': serializer.errors,
            'message': "Your custom error message",
            'code': "400",
            'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        }
    return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
```

You can then access the different elements of the dict you passed along with your response such as `data` or `message` in the view where you render the data.

Comment: I get the following error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status'

Comment: @methuselah are you sure you entered the correct key in your dictionary and in `status=response_details.status` ? If not, update your question with your updated code and I'll have a look.

Comment: I had to change it to         `return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])` to get it working

Comment: @methuselah Yes my bad, got confused as I've been working a lot with JS recently, I'll update my answer with the correct way of accessing a Python dict.